# Setting state in a reducer yields type error

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I'm returning data via Redux Saga and trying to overwrite my empty default object with the result of a webservice (which returns an object).

My reducer code looks like this.

```
  function newSalesNumber(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'NEWSALESNUMBER_FETCHED':
      return state
        .set("orderHeader.orderId", action.result);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default newSalesNumber;
```

This is returning a type Error

```
uncaught at callGetNewSalesNumber TypeError: state.set is not a function
```

I feel like I'm missing something syntactically. What is the proper way to set.state within the reducer?

Please let me know if you need to see the Saga code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State doesn't have a set. It is not React's setState(). Also you cannot mutate state. Try to find about redux in general, one of the major principles is immutability.

So, you want to do something like this:

```
return {...state, [orderHeader.orderId]:action.result}
```

The ...state is just es6 syntactic sugar for spreading the state.
Read more about spread here: [link](https://www.google.ch/search?q=es6%20spread&oq=es6%20spread&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1823j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you! I had actually tried something similar to this without the spread operator. It isn't valid syntax because of the nested object. orderHeader.orderId any thoughts?

Comment: oh sorry, you're right. Then this should do it:  
[orderHeader.orderId]. @ShawnMatthews I edited the answer